# Cannot create certificate with letsencrypt, or stop the conflicting service

Tags: 16.04, nginx, gitlab, letsencrypt

I'm trying to create a certificate for use with Gitlab. 
When running `letsencrypt certonly -d gitlab.myurl.com`. I get part-way through the process and it says: `The program nginx (process ID xxxxx) is already listening on TCP port 80....`

So naturally I try the below but it doesn't work

```
services@mx5:~$ sudo service nginx stop
Failed to stop nginx.service: Unit nginx.service not loaded.
```

I also tried killing the process via its pid but it just comes back under a new one. Am I using the wrong service name? Doesn't look like it to me but I'm not sure. I did try to stop gitlab but had a similar error message.

```
services@mx5:~$ ps -ef | grep nginx
root     20363 20033  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 runsv nginx
root     20364 20363  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/ngin
root     20365 20363  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx -p /var/opt/gitlab/nginx
gitlab-+ 20366 20365  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
gitlab-+ 20368 20365  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache manager process
gitlab-+ 24537 20365  0 11:10 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
services 25442  1335  0 11:17 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Let me know if any more information is required. I'm quite new to Linux and I'm attempting to follow along with this: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-gitlab-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by stopping the gitlab service. It's called `gitlab-ctl` rather than just gitlab